# How to partially differentiate the integral $\int_{0}^{x/\sqrt{t}}\exp(-\xi^2/4)d\xi$ w.r.t $x$ and $t$?

Tags: integration, analysis, partial-derivative

How do I partially differentiate the following integral:

$$
u(x,t) := \int_{0}^{x/\sqrt{t}}e^{-\xi^2/4} \,\mathrm d \xi
$$

I would like to calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x, t)$ and $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, t)$.

I have tried to solve the indefinite integral:

$$
\int e^{-\xi^2/4} \,\mathrm d \xi
$$

hoping to get a nicer formula, but even the CAS only spit out

$$
\int e^{-\xi^2/4} \,\mathrm d \xi = \sqrt{\pi}\operatorname{erf}\left(\frac{\xi}{2}\right)=2\int_{0}^{\frac{\xi}{2}}e^{-\tau^2}\,\mathrm d\tau
$$

which is of not much help, since it is basically just a slight rearrangement of the orginal function.

I have also tried to apply the fundamental theorem of calculus, by rewriting

$$
u(x,t) := \int_{0}^{g(x,t)}h(\xi)d\xi = H(\xi)\Big|_0^{g(x,t)}=H(g(x,t))-H(0)
$$

but I'm also stuck here.

Comment: what do you think about the problem?

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a much more positive response (more help and fewer votes to close) if you indicate what you have done to solve the problem yourself.  What have you tried?  Where are you stuck?  Unless you show us what you've done, it's hard to know what kind of help is appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for you replies. I've amended my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$u(x,t) = \int_{0}^{x/\sqrt{t}}e^{-\xi^2/4} d \xi$$

Use [Leibnitz rule for integration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x, t)
   = \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4t}\right)
     \frac{d}{dx} \left[\frac{x}{\sqrt t}\right]
   = \exp\left(-\frac{x^2}{4t}\right) \frac{1}{\sqrt t }
$$

Similarly can you calculate $\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}(x, t)$?

Answer (score 5):

**HINT**

Think of
$$
f(z) = \int_0^z e^{-s^2/4}ds
$$
with the property $$f'(z) = e^{-z^2/4}.$$

Note that your $u(x,t) = f(x/\sqrt{t})$. Based on this and using the chain rule, can you figure out the partials you are asking for?

Comment: Thank you for your answer - yes, I was able to use your hint. I prefered Deepesh's answer though, because it is a more general approach.

Comment: @WolfgangP it's the same idea, he just gave you a specific example and i wanted you to do it yourself :-) no hard feelings, he explained the idea very clearly, and I upvoted him as well